# How can i read this firebase database child nodes passing through the User Id?

Tags: android, firebase

This is my firebase database and further more is there. I just want to fetch all latitude and longitude of the users, but i cant pass through the UID

```
"user"

    "ODs4wO19sLcht8bobUKFRVkIzu73" : {
      "Email" : "jik@gmail.com",
      "First Name" : "Dummy",
      "Last Name" : "Name",
      "Latitude" : "22.31179464",
      "Longitude" : "73.18581206",
      "Owner Address" : "bskksos",
      "Profile Image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/streetfood2-4bd8a.appspot.com/o/Profile+Images%2Fcropped-1678023661.jpg?alt=media&token=43a13ac5-3dec-46b4-a38c-3c14475d42fa"
    },
    "OQu7N7hqJ6SLipqFwqutRozDtrz1" : {
      "Email" : "fhfhd@gnail.com",
      "First Name" : "shiv",
      "Last Name" : "singh",
      "Latitude" : "22.31179464",
      "Longitude" : "73.18581206",
      "Mobile Number" : "00000000",
      "Password" : "qwerty",
      "Profile Image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/streetfood2-4bd8a.appspot.com/o/Profile+Images%2Fcropped1324744850.jpg?alt=media&token=20a0efad-fb57-409d-a0d8-d6249366830d"
    },
```

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. In addition: include the [minimum code that shows where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, actually i am new to stackoverflow and know much about formatting code on stackoverflow. Bur somehow i managed. i have include the json as text please go through it.!! @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Thanks. That leaves the question of what you've already tried. The Firebase documentation shows how to read data, so should allow you to get started: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: i know how to read the data. But the question is how can i go through encoded email that is child element of USERS and get its latitude and longitude.

Comment: DataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users/What should i write here");

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to loop over all users:

```
DatabaseReference users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            double lat = userSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
            double lon = userSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
            System.out.println(lat+","+lon);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```